# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Необходимо иметь и современное оборудование, и новые технологии, и работоспособный (,) творческий коллектив…

Answer (score 3):

Возможны два разных случая.

1. Коллектив в объективном смысле "творческий" (театральная труппа, занятая в технически оснащённом шоу, или инновационный отдел предприятия, где нужны изобретатели). Требуется, чтобы этот ТК был "работоспособным". Запятая не нужна.
2. Случай, когда "творческий" наряду с "работоспособным" - два чисто условных эпитета, отражающих желаемые для производственного коллектива т.н. "творческий подход" к делу, квалификацию персонала и слаженность людей в работе. Это взаимодополняющие позитивные качества одного порядка, которые можно рассматривать как однородные определения. Запятая нужна.

Answer (score 2):

Запятую, по-моему, можно и поставить, рассматривая при этом определения "работоспособный" и "творческий" как однородные положительные характеристики коллектива.

Comment:  Alenka, вы хотите сказать, что в вашем примере есть общий признак? Если да, то какой это признак?

Comment: Мне кажется, что они характеризуют существительное с одной, положительной стороны. "Хороший" коллектив - работоспособный и творческий.

Comment: Честно говоря, не уверен. Спрошу у Грамоты.

Comment: [Не во всех](https://books.google.com/books?id=w2YSAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%22&dq=%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=DFznVIS2EILvaLXSgsAC&ved=0CB8Q6AEwATgK). Видимо, все зависит от контекста.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна. Это неоднородное определение. Творческий коллектив (какой?) - работоспособный.

Comment: А мне кажется, здесь два определения характеризуют существительное "коллектив" с одной стороны. Правда, не могу подобрать определения, чтобы заменить эти два...

Comment: Думаю, что творческий коллектив должен быть работоспособным, а не: и работоспособным, и творческим.

Comment: Тогда запятая нужна. См. у Розенталя (http://www.tepka.ru/rozental_2/84.html ):Определения являются однородными... если образуют смысловую градацию (каждое последующее усиливает выражаемый определениями признак).

Comment: slava1947 при градации присутствует перечисление. Если считать пример о/опр-ем, тогда должно быт перечисление: и работоспособный, и творческий. Т.к. Однородные определения связаны каждое непосредственно с определяемым словом и находятся в одинаковых отношениях к нему. Между собой однородные определения связаны **сочинительными союзами и перечислительной интонацией или только интонацией перечисления и соединительными паузами** .

Comment: Здесь, на мой взгляд, разные признаки: указывается деятельность и качество этой деятельности. Поэтому неоднородные. Хотя, в художественной литературе нередки примеры обособления н/о.

Comment: @Alenka, что именно вы хотите заменить?

Comment: Определения можно считать однородными, если каждое из них относится непоср. к опр. сущ. и между ними можно вставить союз "и". Неоднородные опр. могут стать однородными, если можно подвести их под общее родовое понятие. Напр.: Для туристской базы отведен большой, каменный дом. (объед. понятие "благоустроенный")

Comment: Значит, в тех контекстах они считаются однородными. "В редакции газеты сложился работоспособный, творческий коллектив". https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%22&tbm=bks&start=10

Answer (score 1):

Работоспособный коллектив не всегда творческий. Это прилагательные разных разрядов, поэтому не могут быть однородными.

Answer (score 0):

Розенталь на этот счет дает ясный ответ: "Определения однородны, если характеризуют предмет с разных сторон, но в условиях контекста объединены каким-нибудь общим признаком, например сходством производимого впечатления". В Вашем случае общее впечатление - позитивный, креативный, деятельный, активный...коллектив, так что запятая обязательно нужна

Comment: Александр, на мой взгляд, дал исчерпывающий ответ. По поводу общего внешнего признака можно спорить, т.к. слова ''творческий'' и работоспособный" уже включают в себя перечисленные вами эпитеты. Александр прав: в одном случае - определения являются неоднородными, в другом - однородными, в зависимости от смысла. Но я уже (до того как Александр дал ответ) обратился на Грамоту.ру. Надеюсь, что ответят. Интересно и их мнение.

Comment: Уважаемый Серж! Розенталь дает даже такие примеры: "В небе таяло маленькое, золотистое облачко", "Весенний, утренний, тоненький ледок покрывал лужу", "Милые, твердые, красные губы ее все так же морщились...". Его объяснение: эти определения объединены каким-либо общим признаком (внешним видом, сходством производимого впечатления, причинной связью и т.п.)